# Symfony Encore - Webpack and UglifyJs

Tags: symfony, webpack, uglifyjs

A Symfony 4.4 project has been created which is using Encore for Javascript and CSS assets.

Symfony Encore is working, Javascript is generated however I would like to add UglifyJs to reduce the file size.

Since it's Symfony Encore and not Webpack I don't know how to include and configure UglifyJs.

If Uglify is no longer the preferred solution for minification I am open to alternatives.

The default install steps were followed from here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/frontend/encore/installation.html

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
yarn install
```

I tried modifying (more like a hack) to include uglifyjs but it doesn't reduce the file size massively.

```
// webpack.config.js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
    config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
    config.corejs = 3;
    })
    .addExternals(
    {
        jquery: 'jQuery',
        bootstrap: 'bootstrap',
        popper: 'popper',
    }
    )    

;

var webpackConfig = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

webpackConfig.optimization.minimizer = [
   new UglifyJsPlugin() 
];

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

How can I include UglifyJs with Symfony Encore for meaningful file size reductions?

I've tried with the following options to uglify, but my Javascript doesn't work in the browser and listing 100's of reserved words is not really an good option.

```
    uglifyOptions: {
        warnings: false,
        parse: {},
        compress: {},
        mangle: {
            toplevel: true, properties: true, reserved: ['App','$','tooltip']
        },
        output: null,
        toplevel: false,
        keep_classnames: true,
        nameCache: null,
        ie8: false,
        keep_fnames: false,
    }
```

Sample JS file:

```
export default function App() {
    this.init();
}
App.prototype.init = function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
};
```

Called in the HTML via

```
new App();
```

Comment: In which `env` does this happen? The default config should already minify the bundle *for the `prod`* environment. Can you do a production build and verify? Or do you want to do this unconditionally?

Comment: Yes you are correct, long day sorry, there is minification already happening. What is the correct way to configure the minification for `production`? Or to use an alternative minifier like `UglifyJs`? Using `webpackConfig.optimization.minimizer` feels wrong, is there something like `Encore.configMinify()`?

Comment: Encore [uses terser](https://symfony.com/blog/encore-0-21-0-webpack-4-support-copy-files-support-webpackencorebundle#support-for-uglifying-es6-code), and as noted in that link, you use `.configureTerserPlugin()` to configure it.